# How can I port nmap, map, and imap commands to Lua configuration?

Tags: key-bindings, neovim, lua

How can I port `map` commands in my vimrc file to Neovim lua configuration? For example:

```
nmap <silent> <F2> <Plug>(lcn-rename)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use [`vim.api.nvim_set_keymap`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/api.html#nvim_set_keymap())

```
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap(mode, keys, mapping, options)
```

So to port

```
nmap <silent> <F2> <Plug>(lcn-rename)
```

It would look like

```lua
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('n', '<F2>', "<Plug>(lcn-rename')", { noremap = true, silent = true });
```

Alternatively [you can create convenience functions](https://www.notonlycode.org/neovim-lua-config/),

```lua
function map(mode, shortcut, command)
  vim.api.nvim_set_keymap(mode, shortcut, command, { noremap = true, silent = true })
end

function nmap(shortcut, command)
  map('n', shortcut, command)
end

function imap(shortcut, command)
  map('i', shortcut, command)
end
```